# Exponential transformation of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given a random variable $x\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$

What is the distribution of its exponential transformation $y = e^x$?

Comment: It is called a [Log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) RV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $Y=e^X$ for $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is called Log-normal and denoted as $Y\sim\mathcal{LN}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).